# Draw function with glDrawArrays() needs to be called twice for anything to show

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

This is a strange problem. I have a function:

```cpp
void drawLines(std::vector<GLfloat> lines) {
    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);

    //positions
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //colors
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(lines[0]) * lines.size(), &lines[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glUseProgram(pShaderProgram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, lines.size() / 6);
}
```

It draws lines of a specified thickness (this is built into the data of `lines` which contains three floats for position and three floats for color, per point with over 200 points to mark line endings). Calling the function once does not yield any result, even after following with `SwapBuffers(HDC)` and `glFlush()`. However, when I call the function twice, then everything shows. I suspect there is some nuance that I am missing with pushing the buffers through the render pipeline, that might be activated by binding the buffer multiple times. I am unsure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glVertexAttribPointer` expects a buffer bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point in order to establish an association between the generic vertex attribute and the buffer object to source the data from.

However, you bind the buffer with `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2)` *after* the call to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

This is why you need two calls, because the first call will not associate any buffer object to the generic vertex attributes, since likely no buffer was bound before.

The way you are using VAOs is dubious, however, since everything you do in this method/function will already be saved as VAO state. So, you neither need to reestablish the association between generic vertex attributes and buffer objects every time, nor do you need to enable the generic vertex attributes every time you draw.

All of this can be done *once* when doing the vertex specification for the VAO.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am using these same VBOs and VAOs for both texture shaders and simple primitive shaders, so that is why I am restating the structure of the VAO every time I call this function. Should I not be doing this?